# PyQt/PySide - Update main status bar from nested child widget

Tags: pyside6, pyqt6

I have a *QMainWindow* which has the status bar enabled. I then have nested widgets/layouts that make up child page of the *QMainWindow*. Here is a sample hierarchy of how the widgets are arranged:

- *Main (QMainWindow)*

  - *MainView (QWidget)*

    - *MainTab (QWidget)*

      - *MainTabs (QWidget)*

In *MainTabs*, I perform some logic and want to show a message on the status bar that is controlled by *Main*. I found a couple of options searching for solutions. One is doing the chained parent() option, so *self.parent().parent()...* which eventually gets access to the *Main* status bar. Another option is using signals/slots, which is what I am doing.

My current flow is as follows:

- *MainTabs* does the logic and emits *statusUpdate* signal
- *MainTab* connects to *MainTabs.statusUpdate* and emits its own *statusUpdate* signal
- *MainView* connects to *MainTab.statusUpdate* and emits its own *statusUpdate* signal
- *Main* connects to *MainView.statusUpdate* and calls function to update the status bar

I have it working with the multiple signals, but is there a better way to do this? Can the *Main QMainWindow* be accessed directly from a nested widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the top level window using [`window()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#window), but that would be just an assumption: a child object should never *assume* things about its parents, at any level, nor try to directly access its elements.

While using signals (possibly, chained, for complex situations) might be fine, there's no need for this, as long as the QMainWindow uses a *proper* status bar (either created by calling [`statusBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#statusBar) or manually set with `setStatusBar()`).

What you could actually do is to explicitly call `setStatusTip()` in the widget, and then *enforce* the status tip visibility, by creating a [QStatusTipEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstatustipevent.html), then use [`QCoreApplication.sendEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent).

The following example shows a basic widget that is able to emit such event and eventually hides it after a timeout, unless the mouse leaves the widget before that:

```py
class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.button = QPushButton('Update status tip')
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showStatusTip)
        self.statusTimer = QTimer(singleShot=True, 
            interval=2000, timeout=self.hideStatusTip)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hideStatusTip()
        self.statusTimer.stop()

    def showStatusTip(self):
        tip = 'Value is {}'.format(self.spinBox.value())
        QApplication.sendEvent(self, QStatusTipEvent(tip))
        self.statusTimer.start()

    def hideStatusTip(self):
        QApplication.sendEvent(self, QStatusTipEvent(''))
```

Comment: I was not aware of sending events in this manner, so thanks and this will work. I need the status message to be formatted for an error (red color) or success (green), so to accomplish that for now I am just sending the string delimited as such:
`QApplication.sendEvent(self, QStatusTipEvent("INFO|1000|Some message"))`
I am capturing the event in the main window and then parsing the string to get INFO or ERROR, the timeout value and the message. I tried with a custom event, but could not get this going. For now this will do the trick.